# Check if I have an key-driven access to ssh-git repository without cloning it

Tags: git, ssh

I am writing some automation script, and I need to make sure at the beginning, that ssh-key for the git repo, script works with, is properly installed, and repo is accessable. But it should be done without cloning (there are several huge repos, so first check access for all of them, then slowly clone), and without asking a remote password. If remote password is asked, something goes wrong, an error should be reported.

So check git+ssh access, no actual cloning, no password asking. Is it possible? I did not find my way to do it.

I found `git ls-remote` but I did not find a way to skip remote password asking. May be some way to pass an `PasswordAuthentication=no` option to ssh. But I did not managed to figure out how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no " git ls-remote  git@git.my-git.server:my_project/my_repo.git`

It will give `$? == 0` on success, and `$? == 128` if there is no access